# Why does pandas keep becoming an empty data frame when I put my code into a function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variables, pysimplegui

I have a pandas program that edits a CSV file to what I need for work. This program works great when I run it on its own. I am now trying to build a GUI with PySimpleGUI that allows me to select which program I need to run, and then runs it with the correct file attached. My problem is that if I turn my pandas program into a function it does not seem to carry any information over from the CSV except the header (top row) and says 'Empty Dataframe'. I am not sure how to correct this as I cannot call the program without it being in a function. The first code block is the original code, and it works correctly(some information was redacted due to work privacy):

```
df = pd.read_csv('XXX_test_file.csv', sep=',', dtype={'MemberIdentifer': int})

df = df[['MemberIdentifier', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'BirthDate', 'Zip', 'HireDate',
         'MedicalPlan', 'Division', 'GenderCode', 'EmailAddress']]

df['Region'] = pd.Series(dtype=str)
df['Role'] = pd.Series(dtype=str)
df['Company'] = pd.Series(dtype=str)
df['Action'] = pd.Series(dtype=str)
df['PrimaryMemberEmployeeId'] = pd.Series(dtype=str)
df['PrimaryMemberEmail'] = pd.Series(dtype=str)

df.rename(columns={'MemberIdentifier': 'EmployeeId', 'BirthDate': 'DateOfBirth', 'Division': 'Location',
                   'GenderCode': 'Gender', 'Zip': 'ZipCode', 'EmailAddress': 'Email'}, inplace=True)

df = df.reindex(columns=['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Location', 'EmployeeId', 'DateOfBirth', 'Gender', 'ZipCode', 'Email',
                         'Role', 'PrimaryMemberEmail', 'PrimaryMemberEmployeeId', 'HireDate', 'Company', 'Action'
    , 'MedicalPlan'])

# stops copy error
pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)

p = -1
for _ in (df['EmployeeId']):
    p = (p + len(df['EmployeeId']) - (len(df['EmployeeId']) - 1))
    EEID = df['EmployeeId'].iloc[p]

    if df['MedicalPlan'].iloc[p] == 'XXX Health Plan':
        df['Role'].iloc[p] = 'Employee On Plan'


df['PrimaryMemberEmail'] = (df['PrimaryMemberEmployeeId']
                            .map(df.set_index('EmployeeId')['Email'])
                            .fillna(df['PrimaryMemberEmail'])
                            )

df['Company'].fillna('XXX', inplace=True)

df.to_csv('XXX_company.csv', header=True, index=False)
```

Naturally, I thought I could break this into two functions, one to get the CSV ready for data-management, and another to parse through the data. When I do this, the whole system seems to fall apart, however, as the Dataframe becomes empty. I am unsure how to pass the Dataframe into a variable without it wiping clean. I am new and learning, and after much googling, this is still stumping me. Below is the modified code(some information redacted due to work privacy):

```
pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)
dft = pd.read_csv('input_file.csv', sep=',', dtype={'MemberIdentifer': int})
def get_file_and_format(dft):
    df = dft

    df = df[['MemberIdentifier', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'BirthDate', 'Zip', 'HireDate',
             'MedicalPlan', 'Division', 'GenderCode', 'EmailAddress']]
    df['Region'] = pd.Series(dtype=str)
    df['Role'] = pd.Series(dtype=str)
    df['Company'] = pd.Series(dtype=str)
    df['Action'] = pd.Series(dtype=str)
    df['PrimaryMemberEmployeeId'] = pd.Series(dtype=str)
    df['PrimaryMemberEmail'] = pd.Series(dtype=str)
    df.rename(columns={'MemberIdentifier': 'EmployeeId', 'BirthDate': 'DateOfBirth', 'Division': 'Location',
                       'GenderCode': 'Gender', 'Zip': 'ZipCode', 'EmailAddress': 'Email'}, inplace=True)

    df = df.reindex(
        columns=['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Location', 'EmployeeId', 'DateOfBirth', 'Gender', 'ZipCode', 'Email',
                 'Role', 'PrimaryMemberEmail', 'PrimaryMemberEmployeeId', 'HireDate', 'Company', 'Action',
                 'MedicalPlan'])

    # stops copy error
    pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)
    return df


def parse_data(df):

    p = -1
    for _ in (df['EmployeeId']):
        p = (p + len(df['EmployeeId']) - (len(df['EmployeeId']) - 1))
        EEID = df['EmployeeId'].iloc[p]

        if df['MedicalPlan'].iloc[p] == 'Health Plan':
            df['Role'].iloc[p] = 'Employee On Plan'



    df['PrimaryMemberEmail'] = (df['PrimaryMemberEmployeeId']
                            .map(df.set_index('EmployeeId')['Email'])
                            .fillna(df['PrimaryMemberEmail'])
                            )

    df['Company'].fillna('XXX_company', inplace=True)




file = get_file_and_format(dft)
```

Comment: you are returning `df` from `get_file_and_format` into a variable `file`. Did you print what is being returned?...where are you calling `parse_data`?

Comment: i figured out the problem. CSV was corrupted.